# Encrypt MySQL Password in Batch File / Secure Batch File

Tags: encryption, batch-file

I have a Windows batch file which runs periodically to update data on my MySQL database. I now want to make the batch file secure so that no-one can see the password used to connect to the database. I have thought of two potential solutions:

1. Encrypt the password in the batch file
2. Encrypt the entire file.

Id prefer to go with option 1. Is there a quick method to encrypt a password which can be used in a batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only encrypting the password just moves the problem to how you secure the decryption key.

If you're on NTFS you should secure the whole file instead. On the file properties encryption is accessed by the Advanced... button under Attributes, and access controls are on the Security tab.

Comment: The checkbox for encryption is greyed out. I think i need the Pro edition of XP to do that. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: @Santiago - Using the access controls would be sufficient, provided both your user account and hard drive are also secure.